# Why do python Processes behave differently with barrier.wait()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, barrier

**TLDR**

Selecting the process that gets `0` back from `barrier.wait()` biases the order of the processes on the next iteration. Why?

**Full Story**

The below problem is a simple version of my actual problem.

Lets say I have the following multiprocessing problem:
I have a string (named output), n processes, n characters (not spaces), and N iterations.

Example: `output, n, characters,  N = '', 3, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 4`

For each iteration, every process should append its character to the string (in any order). After each iteration, a space character should be appended to the string.

For the example, the output could be:
`output = 'bca abc bac cab'`

To get this functionality I use the multiprocessing library.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Value, Manager, Barrier
import ctypes

def print_characters(lock, barrier, character, N, output):
    for i in range(N):
        lock.acquire()
        output.value += character
        lock.release()
        _id = barrier.wait() # get an id for each thread (although not promised to be assigned randomly)
        if _id == 0: # select 1 and get this thread to append the ' '
            lock.acquire()
            output.value += ' '
            lock.release()
        barrier.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    output = manager.Value(ctypes.c_char_p, "")
    num_processes = 3
    characters = 'abc'
    N = 4

    lock, barrier  = Lock(), Barrier(num_processes)
    processes = []

    for i in range(num_processes):
        p = Process(target=print_characters, args=(lock, barrier, characters[i], N, output))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print(output.value)
```

Cool....

According to the documentation for [`Barrier.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Barrier),

> When all the [processes] to the barrier have called this function, they are all released simultaneously.

So, if all `n` processes are released simultaneously, I wondered if this would cause a kind of "uniform random race condition" on the processes such that each process had an equal chance of getting to the `lock.acquire()` on the next iteration.

I don't really care about the order but it might be nice to know if I have the processes doing something different in the future.

To see this if this was the case I counted the number of times that each character came in which position:

```
output = output.value.split(' ')[:-1]
c = [[0]*num_processes for i in range(num_processes)]
for line in output:
    for i, character in enumerate(line):
        ind = characters.find(character)
        c[ind][i] += 1
print(c)
```

For N = 1000, this is one output I got:

```
[[1000    0    0]
 [   0  948   52]
 [   0   52  948]]
```

:| ok?

So out of 1000 iterations, the process with the first character was always first. That didn't seem very random.

I then made one change in the `print_characters` function:

`if _id == 1:`

And I got:

```
[[254 254 492]
 [489 489  22]
 [257 257 486]]
```

Not uniform random but also not as biased.

Changing the number of processes (assuming the cpu can support it) and thus the number of characters shows this same effect:

**Selecting the process that gets `0` back from `barrier.wait()` biases the order of the processes on the next iteration.**

Why?

Comment: "get a random id for each thread" - `wait` does not promise to return random values. It just promises that each process gets a different value.

Comment: True, I'll update the question. I still don't see why the processes aren't actually released 'simultaneously' as said in the documentation.

Comment: "they are all released simultaneously" doesn't mean "each process is immediately scheduled and starts running with no delay, right now". It just means they're no longer blocked by the barrier. Even the unblocking doesn't have to happen absolutely simultaneously.

Comment: I see, I was definitely confused by "simultaneously". So the processes get unblocked in some "relatively-the-same" order with very short delays between unblocking each process?

Comment: I would bet that “simultaneously” here means “sequentially, as quickly as possible”, i.e. Python goes through the list of waiting processes and releases each one in turn, without any special measures to guarantee simultaneity. In which case, they’re probably released in the same order that they call `wait()`, but a few clock cycles apart.

Comment: They seem to be released in the same order when choosing an _id = 0 like in the example. I was confused why having a process do some extra work in between `wait`s would effect to order on the next iteration.